# Dojo content pane and ssjs

Tags: xpages

I have a content pane that I'm loading with some dynamic content - a few fields and a button.  When clicking the button, no ssjs executes.  For simplicity I'm just setting a sessionScope variable and it's not getting set.  If I make the pane content static then ssjs fires fine.

So the question is SHOULD a button that executes ssjs work if it is loaded dynamically into a dojo content pane?

This app is NOT using ExtLib.

Comment: Let me also add that the dynamic content being loaded is another xpage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this won't work because the dijit.layout.ContentPane won't load scripts. You should use a [dojox.layout.ContentPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/layout/ContentPane.html) and set the property 'executeScript' to true. Then it should load and fire all actions correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up going in another direction.